# Slokams for Navaratri first three days for durga, next three days for lakshmi and last 3 days for saraswathi

Tags: lakshmi, durga, saraswati, navrathri

There are simple slokas consisting 4 lines to be recited on these 9 days to the devis. First three days for durga, next three days for Lakshmi and last 3 days for saraswathi. Do anybody know these slokas? If so please post an answer.

Comment: Are you searching for this sloka "ॐ खड्‌गं चक्रगदेषुचापपरिघाञ्छूलं भुशुण्डीं शिरः
शङ्खं संदधतीं करैस्त्रिनयनां सर्वाङ्गभूषावृताम्।
नीलाश्मद्युतिमास्यपाददशकां सेवे महाकालिकां
यामस्तौत्स्वपिते हरौ कमलजो हन्‍तुं मधुं कैटभम्॥१॥" It's for Durga

Comment: Like for Lakshmi and saraswathi do you have? Will ledt you know after all the slokas. The slokas to be told at navarati time.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you are looking for this. This is Dhyana shloka for Mahalakshmi recited during Chandi Path: ॐ अक्षस्रक्‌परशुं गदेषुकुलिशं पद्मं धनुष्कुण्डिकां
दण्डं शक्तिमसिं च चर्म जलजं घण्टां सुराभाजनम्।
शूलं पाशसुदर्शने च दधतीं हस्तैः प्रसन्नाननां
सेवे सैरिभमर्दिनीमिह महालक्ष्मीं सरोजस्थिताम्

Comment: And this for Mahasaraswati "ॐ घण्टाशूलहलानि शङ्‌खमुसले चक्रं धनुः सायकं
हस्ताब्जैर्दधतीं घनान्तविलसच्छीतांशुतुल्यप्रभाम्।
गौरीदेहसमुद्भवां त्रिजगतामाधारभूतां महा-
पूर्वामत्र सरस्वतीमनुभजे शुम्भादिदैत्यार्दिनीम्॥"

Comment: will cross check and tell tomorrow--probably in North you people may tell those slokas but in south there was a publication from kanchi mutt in 1975 by HHMaha periava. Will confirm tomorrow.

Comment: Ok check it... but these are only Dhyana Shloka... and not the Chandi Slokas ie. Not among 700 verses...

Comment: I appreciate your effort.

Comment: You can recite Durga Suktam,Sri Suktam and Medha Suktam for 3 days each for Durga,Lakshmi and Saraswati respectively.I have done the same last year.They are not 4 liners but not very lengthy like Sri Rudram either.

Comment: Good suggestion--but due to office work if the slokas are short we can recite and be peaceful. Will give those slokas in due course.

Comment: Tezz : Please let me know the meaning of this Sloka

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Durga  [First 3 days]**

> दुर्गे स्मृता हरसि भीतिमशेषजन्तोः
>   स्वस्थैः स्मृता मतिमतीवशुभां ददासि।
>   दारिद्र्यदुःखभयहारिणि का त्वदन्या
>   सर्वोपकारकरणाय सदार्द्रचित्ता ॥
>
> **Durge Smrita Harasi Bhitim Ashesha-Jantoh
>   Swasthaih Smrita Matim Ateeva-Shubhaam Dadasi
>   Daridrya-Duhkha-Bhaya-harini Ka Twadanya
>   Sarvopakara-karanaya Sadardra-chitta**

O Mother Durga! When Thou art merely remembered, Thou extirpatest all fears and afflictions of entire world.
And contemplated by the healthy people, Thou conferest them highly excellent and auspicious intellect.
O Great Mother! O Dispeller of afflictions of sorrow, fear and poverty! No one else is there in the world other than Thee who is compassionate towards others to do their good.

**Lakshmi [Next 3 days]**

> लक्ष्मीं क्षीरसमुद्रराजतनयां श्रीरङ्गधामेश्वरीं
>   दासीभूतसमस्तदेववनितां लोकैकदीपाङ्कुराम्।
>   श्रीमन्मन्दकटाक्षलब्धविभवद्ब्रह्मेन्द्रगङ्गाधरां
>   त्वां त्रैलोक्यकुटुम्बिनीं सरसिजां वन्दे मुकुन्दप्रियाम्॥
>
> **lakShmeeM kSheerasamudraraaja tanayaaM SreeraMgadhaamESvareem |
>   daaseebhoota samastadEva vanitaaM lOkaika deepaaMkuraam ||
>   SreemanmaMda kaTaakSha labdha vibhavad-brahmEMdra gaMgaadharaam |
>   tvaaM trailOkya kuTuMbineeM sarasijaaM vaMdE mukuMdapriyaam ||**

O Great MahaLakshmi! I pay obeisances to thee. Thou art the daughter of Milk Ocean, the Lord of Oceans. Thou art the Lord of abode of Shree Ranga Narayana and all the Devas become like Thy subservient servants to serve Thee alone. Thou alone art the light guiding us in this world.
By obtaining the side glances of eyes of Shree Vishnu, Thou hast created Brahma, Indra and Shiva.
Salutations to Thee, O Ocean-born! Thou art the beloved of Mukunda, and art the Mother of all the three worlds.

**Saraswathi [Last 3 days**]

> **या कुन्देन्दुतुषारहारधवला या शुभ्रवस्त्रावृता
>
>   या वीणावरदण्डमण्डितकरा या श्वेतपद्मासना।
>
>   या ब्रह्माच्युतशङ्करप्रभृतिभिर्देवैः सदा पूजिता
>
>   सा मां पातु सरस्वती भगवती निःशेषजाड्यापहा॥**
>
> **Yaa Kundendu-Tussaara-Haara-Dhavalaa Yaa Shubhra-Vastraavrtaa
>   Yaa Viinnaa-Vara-Danndda-Mannddita-Karaa Yaa Shveta-Padmaasanaa |
>   Yaa Brahma-Acyuta-Shankara-Prabhrtibhir-Devaih Sadaa Puujitaa
>   Saa Maam Paatu Sarasvati Bhagavatii Nihshessa-Jaaddya-Apahaa **

Who is Pure White like Jasmine, with the Coolness of Moon, Brightness of Snow and Shine like the Garland of Pearls; and Who is Covered with Pure White Garments,
Whose Hands are Adorned with Veena (a stringed musical instrument) and the Boon-Giving Staff; And Who is Seated on Pure White Lotus,
Who is Always Adored by Lord Brahma, Lord Acyuta (Lord Vishnu), Lord Shankara and Other Devas,
O Goddess Saraswati, Protect me and Remove my Ignorance completely.

**Source--A special small book issued by Kanchi Kamakodi Mutt, Tamilnadu in the year 1975.**

> **Note--I request the members of this HSE to recite the slokas multiple times to get the blessings of three devis and maintain healthy life.**

Comment: Good ones ,the first one is from Durga Sapta Sloki.The last one from Saraswati Stotram (Agastya Kruth).Not sure of the Laksmi Sloka.

Comment: Thanks Rickross--Lakshmi is from Lakshmi Ashtotra sloka.

Comment: @Jase-  Welcome  always.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know,there are no specific Slokas as such.

Any Slokas ,Stotras can be used to seek Goddesses' blessings.

Few such simple Slokas are the following;

> **Durga**--namaste sharaNye shive saanukampe |  namaste jagad vyaapike vishva roope ||  namaste jagad vandye paadaaravinde |  namaste jagat
>   taariNe traahi durge ||
>
> **Lakshmi**--vanday lakshmeem para shivamayeem   shuddha jaamboonad
>   aabhaam  tejoroopaam kanaka vasanaam   sarpa bhooshojjvalaangeem | 
>   beejaapooram kanaka kalasham   hema padmam dadhaanaam  aadyaam
>   shakteem sakala jananeem   vishNu vaamaanka sansthaam ||
>
> **Saraswati**--saraswatee divyam drushTaa veeNaa pustaka dhaariNee  |  hamsavaaha samaayuktaa vidyaa daanakaree mama ||  prathamam bhaaratee
>   naama dviteeyancha saraswatee | truteeyam shaaradaa devee chaturtham
>   hamsavaahinee  |

[Source for all the  Slokas](http://www.bharatiweb.com/?cat=11)

Still better, if you have time, to recite [Durga Suktam](http://www.vignanam.org/veda/durga-suktam-english.html) (on 1st three days),[Sri Suktam](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/devi_lakshmi-sri_suktam.php)(on next 3 days for Lakshmi) & [Medha Suktam](http://www.celextel.org/vedichymns/medhasuktam.html)(for Saraswati on last 3 days).

Last year we had done the same.